# Is obtaining convergence rate always more difficult and more important than providing proof of convergence for optimization methods?

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

In the field of deterministic and stochastic optimization, Is obtaining convergence rate always more difficult and more important than providing proof of convergence for optimization methods?

For example, method like SGD, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mostly depends on **what** is converging. In most cases, proving the convergence of a sequence is easier and `less important' than proving the rate of convergence of this very sequence. But in many cases, the rate and the convergence itself are proved for different sequences.

Imagine that $S = \{ x_k \}_{k=1}^\infty \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a sequence generated by some algorithm. You can analyze the convegence of $S$, or alternatively, you can analyze $F = \{ f(x_k) \}_{k=1}^\infty$.

In many cases, proving the rate of convergence of $F$ to an optimal value is easier than just proving the fact that the sequence $S$ itself converges to an optimal vector. The usefulness of each proof depends on the application. There are cases in which you are not interested in the distance of $x_k$ to an optimal vector and do not care about the value of $f(x_k)$, and there are other cases in which you care about $f(x_k)$ being small, regardless of how $x_k$ is actually close to an optimal vector.

Comment: can you please provide some examples? For SGD, it seems like the majority of the literature discusses the convergence rate while the proof of convergence is more involved than the convergence rate proof.

Comment: For a sequence $a_n$, if $\mathbb{E} [a_n - a] \rightarrow 0$ then $a_n$ is called "converging in mean to $a$". Thus, if you proved that $\mathbb{E} [f(x_n) - f^*] \leq a_n$ for $a_n$ which convergence to zero, which almost always happens, then you already proved that $f(x_n)$ converges. You do not need a separate proof.

Note that convergence in mean implies convergence in probability. That is, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} Pr( f(x_n) - f^* > 0 ) = 0$, which is the "common" type of convergence for a random variable.